# Button onClick FadeIn Text

Tags: javascript, html, button, fadein, fadeout

I'd like that somebody could give me an heads-up with the code to achieve this events:

1. User clicks a button;
2. Button disappears;
3. Text fades in saying "Saved!" in the **SAME POSITION** of the button;
4. Text fades out;
5. Button (from 2nd step) reappears.

Here's the code of the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="gravarpalp" value="Save" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add code for your attempt? And we can help advise the best ways to improve it?

Comment: Yeah, you  need to make an attempt. SO isn't a free freelancer service. :-) This would be fairly easy with jQuery.

Comment: Don't take me wrong. I've already tried and did the button to disappear but couldn't manage to make the text appear and disappear at the same position of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#saveme').click(function() {
        $('#saveme').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#saved').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $('#saved').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $('#saveme').fadeIn('slow', function() {

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="saved" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;display:none">Saved</div>
<input type="submit" name="gravarpalp" value="Save" id="saveme" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @FábioMartinho : Glad that you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to accomplish this.
First, put the controls inside of a div with the following css properties set

```
<div>
<span id="fadeSpan" style='position: relative; display: none;>Saved!</span>
<input id="fadeButton" type="submit" name="gravarpalp" value="Save" style='position: relative;' onclick='fadeEffect();' />
</div>
```

Then add the following function in a script tag.  This isn't tested though, it's just to get you started.

```
function() fadeEffect(){
     $('#fadeButton').fadeToggle();
     $('#fadeSpan').fadeToggle();
     setTimeout(function(){
          $('#fadeButton').fadeToggle();
          $('#fadeSpan').fadeToggle();
     }, 3000);

}
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute ;)

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this link.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ab564345-dcc8-4c85-b56c-ff6d3097d905/) Looks like you should just be able to set the `ForeColor` of a Label to a color value that has a different alpha value.

```
button1.Visible = false;

//make label fade in (alpha value++)
//once opacity reaches 255, make it fade out (alpha value--)

button1.Visible = true;
```

I think you will need some sort of timer so the fade in and out isn't so instant. I'll try explaining better if you need.

EDIT: Sorry, I assumed this was a WinForms app... This won't work for a web application. Try using jQuery or javascript.